# Self-signed SLL certificate for Nextcloud Onion: "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, tor

### Context

After setting up a self-hosted nextcloud server on Ubuntu 22.10 over a tor domain, I created a self-signed SLL certificate using the script below:

### Code

This script first

- generates the certificate authority (CA) and SSL certificates, and then it adds the CA private key to: `"/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_key_filename"` and reloads the trusted ca certificates with:

```bash
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

- It also adds the SSL prublic and private key and the full chain certificate into Nextcloud.
- The `fullchain.pem` consists of the SSL certificate, followed by the CA certificate.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Here is the list of certificates and their description:
# First you create your own certificate authority.
CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME="ca-key.pem"
CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME="ca.pem"
# Same file as ca.pem except different file extension and content.
CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME="ca.crt"

# Then you create a SSL certificate.
SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME="cert-key.pem"

# Then create a sign-request (for your own CA to sign your own SSL certificate)
CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME="cert.csr"
SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME="extfile.cnf"

# Then create the signed public SSL cert.
SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME="cert.pem"

# Then merge the CA and SLL cert into one.
MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME="fullchain.pem"

setup_tor_ssl() {
  local onion_address="$1"

  # Create domains accepted by certificate.
  local domains
  #domains="DNS:$onion_address,IP:127.0.0.1"
  #domains="DNS:localhost,IP:$onion_address" # IP onion does not work
  #domains="DNS:*.$onion_address" # Does not work.
  #domains="DNS:$onion_address" # Does not work.
  domains="DNS:localhost,DNS:$onion_address" # Works for localhost
  echo "domains=$domains.end_without_space"

  delete_target_files

  # Generate and apply certificate.
  generate_ca_cert "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  generate_ssl_certificate "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME" "$SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME" "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$domains"

  verify_certificates "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"

  merge_ca_and_ssl_certs "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"

  install_the_ca_cert_as_a_trusted_root_ca "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"

  add_certs_to_nextcloud "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME" "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME" "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"
}

generate_ca_cert() {
  local ca_private_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_key_filename="$2"

  # Generate RSA
  openssl genrsa -aes256 -out "$ca_private_key_filename" 4096

  # Generate a public CA Cert
  openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key "$ca_private_key_filename" -out "$ca_public_key_filename"
}

generate_ssl_certificate() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_private_key_filename="$2"
  local ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename="$3"
  local signed_domains_filename="$4"
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$5"
  local ssl_private_key_filename="$6"
  local domains="$7"
  # Example supported domains:
  # DNS:your-dns.record,IP:257.10.10.1

  # Create a RSA key
  openssl genrsa -out "$ssl_private_key_filename" 4096

  # Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)
  openssl req -new -sha256 -subj "/CN=yourcn" -key "$ssl_private_key_filename" -out "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename"

  # Create a `extfile` with all the alternative names
  echo "subjectAltName=$domains" >>"$signed_domains_filename"

  # optional
  #echo extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth >> "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename"

  # Create the public SSL certificate.
  openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in "$ca_sign_ssl_cert_request_filename" -CA "$ca_public_key_filename" -CAkey "$ca_private_key_filename" -out "$ssl_public_key_filename" -extfile "$signed_domains_filename" -CAcreateserial
}

verify_certificates() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$2"
  openssl verify -CAfile "$ca_public_key_filename" -verbose "$ssl_public_key_filename"
}

merge_ca_and_ssl_certs() {
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_key_filename="$2"
  local merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename="$3"

  cat "$ssl_public_key_filename" >"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
  cat "$ca_public_key_filename" >>"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
}

install_the_ca_cert_as_a_trusted_root_ca() {
  local ca_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ca_public_cert_filename="$2"

  # The file in the ca-certificates dir must be of extension .crt:
  openssl x509 -outform der -in "$ca_public_key_filename" -out "$ca_public_cert_filename"

  # First remove any old cert if it existed.
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_cert_filename"
  sudo update-ca-certificates

  # TODO: Verify target directory exists.
  # On Debian & Derivatives:
  #- Move the CA certificate (`"$ca_private_key_filename"`) into `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt`.
  sudo cp "$ca_public_cert_filename" "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_cert_filename"

  # TODO: Verify target file exists.

  # TODO: Verify target file MD5sum.

  # Update the Cert Store with:
  sudo update-ca-certificates
}

add_certs_to_nextcloud() {
  local ssl_public_key_filename="$1"
  local ssl_private_key_filename="$2"
  local merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename="$3"

  # First copy the files into nextcloud.
  # Source: https://github.com/nextcloud-snap/nextcloud-snap/issues/256
  # (see nextcloud.enable-https custom -h command).
  #sudo cp ca.pem /var/snap/nextcloud/current/ca.pem
  sudo cp "$ssl_public_key_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$ssl_public_key_filename"
  sudo cp "$ssl_private_key_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$ssl_private_key_filename"
  sudo cp "$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename" /var/snap/nextcloud/current/"$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"

  # CLI sudo /snap/bin/nextcloud.enable-https custom Says:
  sudo /snap/bin/nextcloud.enable-https custom "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$ssl_public_key_filename" "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$ssl_private_key_filename" "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$merged_ca_ssl_cert_filename"
}

delete_target_files() {
  rm "$CA_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$CA_SIGN_SSL_CERT_REQUEST_FILENAME"
  rm "$SIGNED_DOMAINS_FILENAME"
  rm "$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  rm "$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$CA_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$CA_PUBLIC_CERT_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$SSL_PUBLIC_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$SSL_PRIVATE_KEY_FILENAME"
  sudo rm "/var/snap/nextcloud/current/$MERGED_CA_SSL_CERT_FILENAME"

}
```

### Output

The output of this script can be read as:

```bash
$src/main.sh -h
domains=DNS:some_onion.onion,IP:127.0.0.1.end_without_space
rm: cannot remove 'ca.pem': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'cert.csr': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'extfile.cnf': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'cert.pem': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'fullchain.pem': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.pem': No such file or directory
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
................................................................................................................................................................................++++
...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Enter pass phrase for ca-key.pem:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for ca-key.pem:
Enter pass phrase for ca-key.pem:
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:so
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:state3
Locality Name (eg, city) []:locality3
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:org3
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:orgunit3
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:cn3
Email Address []:email3@email.com
Generating RSA private key, 4096 bit long modulus (2 primes)
...................................................................++++
.............................................++++
e is 65537 (0x010001)
Signature ok
subject=CN = yourcn
Getting CA Private Key
Enter pass phrase for ca-key.pem:
cert.pem: OK
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates-java (20220719) ...
done.
Updating Mono key store
Mono Certificate Store Sync - version 6.8.0.105
Populate Mono certificate store from a concatenated list of certificates.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

Importing into legacy system store:
I already trust 124, your new list has 124
Import process completed.

Importing into BTLS system store:
I already trust 124, your new list has 124
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Installing custom certificate... done
Restarting apache... done
```

### Error Message

After running the script successfully, I can manually import the `ca.crt` into brave at: brave://settings/certificates This ensures https works for https://localhost:81 . However, when I open the tor browser in brave, and visit the `some_onion.onion` it returns:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection
> some_onion.onion sent an invalid response.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

### Question

How can I ensure the certificate is trusted on both the `some_onion.onion` link, as well as on localhost?

### Doubt

0. I am unsure whether:

```bash
echo "subjectAltName=DNS:some_onion_link.onion"
```

is permitted. for an SSL certificate. I wonder why the tor version of Brave does not show why the certificate is not trusted.

Comment: `adds the CA private key to: "/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/$ca_public_key_filename"` -- that must be the CA root (aka selfsigned) **certificate** not the private key (ever!) _or_ the public key. And it must be in a filename with suffix `.crt` as specified on the man page for `update-ca-certificates` -- is it? Your script makes it `ca.pem` which _is_ a cert but is NOT named with `.crt` as required, and the log confirms nothing was actually added to the truststore. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: Thank you for your constructive feedback! Indeed I had to add the `ca.crt` instead of the `ca.pem`. After manually adding the `ca.crt` to the Brave browser, I was able to verify the certificates are generated successfully for https://localhost:81. However, for the `some_onion.onion` it still throws an error. I updated the code in the question, and error description to reflect these changes.

Comment: Thank you, I agree it is not about programming or development and I voted with a close flag for that reason. The question is answered [here](https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/23502/32892). Without your feedback it would have been significantly more difficult to fix.